# how to send touch event at position at x and y to your own application?

Tags: android, touch

I have tried lot of similar questions and wrote some code with my best understanding if concept, but still my application failed to register the touch event after injecting to my own application.

In the following application, when the user presses the VOLUME UP button, then the touch event in position `(finalPosX,finalPosY)` is injected, and event listner should be able to catch the input and should display simple `toast` to the Activity.

i have used `dispatchTouchEvent()` to inject the event but unable to catch in ClickListner.

what am i doing wrong?

ClickListner:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ACTION_DOWN",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Injecting Touch Event:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch(keyCode)
    {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

            moveTaskToBack(true);

            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
            SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100,
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    finalPosX,
                    finalPosY,
                    0
            );
            dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You are listening for a Click. A Click consists of two events ( DOWN and UP ) which have to happen in a rather short time span. You only dispatch one event ( DOWN ). So maybe you should dispatch/ listen for the same type of event(s)?